# How do I get my combo-box to show all three fields currently only shows one?

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010

I'm almost done with this nightmare that I've been working on for over a week. I've got the combo-box to work but it only displays one of the values/fields that I wish it to display.

I want it to display the Serial #, HS Model, and the Recd Date. Currently it will only show the Recd date.

The combo-box's Row Source is as follows:

```
SELECT [Recd Date],[Serial #],[HS Model] 
FROM ModelListQuery 
WHERE [HS Model] = Forms![Coding Pop Up]![Coding_drop_down] 
ORDER BY [Recd Date] DESC , [Serial #], [HS Model];
```

It is also unbound. I don't see or believe there's any syntax error here and think I might be forgetting or am unaware of a property on the Property Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has once again been solved by myself. Something as simple as adjusting the "Column Count" to "3" provided the three different columns that I needed where it was previously only set to 1 that's why it was only displaying 1 of the fields from the query.

Also adjusting the Columns Widths and List Widths to my preference.